# Cardinality of a power set $2^{2^A}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The question I want to answer is : if $A$ is finite set of cardinality $2$, find $2^{2^A}$

I know that $|2^{2^{A}}| = 2^{2^{|A|}}$, but does this mean that there are 16 elements in the power set?

Such as $$\{\varnothing\}, \{\{\varnothing\}\},\{\{0\}\}, \{\{1\}\},\{\{0,1\}\},\{\varnothing,\{0\}\}, \{\{\varnothing\},1\}, \{\varnothing,\{0,1\}\},\{\{0\},\{1\}\}, \{\{0\},\{0,1\}\}, \{\{1\},\{0,1\}\}\}, \{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\}\}, \{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\}\}, \{ \varnothing,\{1\},\{0,1\}\}, \{\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}, \{ \varnothing,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$$

Please correct me if I’m wrong, thank you so much!

Comment: Note that we usually set $\varnothing = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct except that we denote the null set using either $\varnothing$ or $\{\}$, and not using $\{\varnothing\}$. So the power set is as follows
\begin{multline}
\{
\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{0\}\}, \{\{1\}\},\{\{0,1\}\},\\
\{\varnothing,\{0\}\}, \{\varnothing,\{1\}\}, \{\varnothing,\{0,1\}\},\{\{0\},\{1\}\}, \{\{0\},\{0,1\}\}, \{\{1\},\{0,1\}\}, \\
\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\}\}, \{\varnothing,\{0\},\{0,1\}\}, \{ \varnothing,\{1\},\{0,1\}\}, \{\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}, \{ \varnothing,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\} \\
\}
\end{multline}